# Collision detection not working as intended on all platforms

Tags: c#, windows-8, xna, collision-detection

This question is going to sound odd because I really don't understand how this could be possible but here goes. I have some collision code for a 2D game of mine which works perfectly fine on Windows, Xbox, WP7, WP8. But for some odd reason the exact same code does not work when I run my game as a Windows 8 Metro App. What's even weirder is, the code works when I run the same project on my Surface but when I run it on my PC the bullets just go straight through the enemy. I don't think posting the code would be of any use since the code is identical where ever I use it and KNOW for a fact it works. If anyone knows how this is even possible please let me know. If you want me to post the code then let me know.

I'll explain a bit of what the code is doing:

- Loops through all the player's bullets

  - Loops through all the enemies

    - If rectangle collision takes place

      - If per pixel collision takes place

        - Kill enemy, remove bullet etc.

The game runs fine as an XNA game on my PC which is the same PC I use to test it as a metro app.

Comment: It seems the code is getting to the rectangle collision part and not even going inside the pixel collision if statement.

Comment: Try it on a Windows 7 computer maybe.

Comment: I can't try a metro app on Windows 7.

Comment: Use some breakpoints and see what's wrong.

Comment: The code is breaking (no exceptions etc), it simply won't return true for pixel collision even though it is true and works fine on other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pixel values to test for collision, you may be trying to use DIP (device independent pixels) pixels thinking they are screen location pixels (something new with Metro, in fact, it's the default).

Set your app to run in simulation mode and set the sim's screen resolution to: 1366x768. Does it suddenly work correctly? if so, then it's a DIP issue.

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173(v=vs.85).aspx

notice the formula halfway down the page: DIPs = pixels / (DPI/96.0)

Comment: That sounds like the thing that makes the most sense. I tried running the simulator with the resolution you said but it still didn't work. However I do believe this is the reason it isn't working so i'll look into the DIPs thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a computer speed problem.  Does your game-loop work on a static timer, or do you throw updates/draws as fast as you can?  It's possible the bullets aren't colliding because on one update they're in front of the enemy, and on the next they're behind.  Try 'widening' the enemies or bullets as a debug - that may fix it.  If this is the case, you may have to do some bullet updating within the update to make sure it hits all the locations in-between. and doesn't teleport through the enemies.

Comment: The game loop isn't running on a timer, the loop is still the same as when I created the project (default loop). I don't think that is the issue because it takes several seconds for the bullet to go past the enemy. I see the bullet itself on top of the enemy for atleast a whole second.